# Not able to catch the emitted signal into the QML from Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-signals

I am learning Qt with C++.

Recently I tried to emit a signal from C++ and based on this event change I tried to update something in `QML`. The `emit` is not working. In fact debugging the code tells me that the line of code just above the `emit` and after the `emit` has worked. But `emit` itself is not working.

According to my understanding till now, you `emit` a signal from C++ and `on`+`signal name` is used inside the `QML` to access that event.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Here is the simplified version of the problem:

`emitsignal.h`

```
#ifndef EMITSIGNAL_H
#define EMITSIGNAL_H

#include <QObject>

class EmitSignal : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EmitSignal(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int add(int, int);

signals:
    void mySignal();

public slots:
};

#endif // EMITSIGNAL_H
```

`emitsignal.cpp`

```
#include "emitsignal.h"

#include <QDebug>

EmitSignal::EmitSignal(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

int EmitSignal::add(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;

    qDebug() << z;

    emit mySignal();

    return x + y;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "emitsignal.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<EmitSignal>("com", 1, 0, "EmitSignal");

    EmitSignal em;
    em.add(1,2);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import com 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    EmitSignal {
    id: emitSignal
    onMySignal: console.log('Inside the function')
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `qmlRegisterType` is used, the type is being registered, so the `EmitSignal` object with the `id:emitSignal` is different from the `em` object (unless the class implements a singleton but in your case it is not), even if the signal is issued for the object em will not be issued for the item with `id:emitSignal`.

If you want them to be the same object you must use [`setContextProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) and make the connections with [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html), also you should not call the method that emits the signal before the `QML` window loads.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "emitsignal.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    EmitSignal em;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("EmitSignal", &em); // EmitSignal is the id

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    em.add(1,2);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Connections {
        target: EmitSignal
        onMySignal: console.log('Inside the function')
    }
}
```

References:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html

Comment: I am doing the object creation inside the class and not in the main (In my application), so there is no way of creating an engine and loading it from ouside of main. Or is there a work around?

Comment: No my class is not implementing singleton.

Comment: It works with the actual question so I have accepted it as the answer. No problem with that. But I would like to set this context property inside a `class`, and not in `main()` that's the problem.

Comment: passing pointers to objects across methods/classes is bad. That's what I have read.

Comment: I will make a simplified version of the problem and will share with you in few minutes.